# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, internet connection doesn't work, but network still can access machine

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet

Last night the machine was working fine. This morning, no internet access.

I'm working with a wired Ethernet connection.
I can ping the router, but not google.
I am able to access shared files on the machine from another computer through the wired network.

Other machines on the network can access the internet. It's only the Ubuntu box that can't get internet.

I can ping google by address but not by name.

output of `lsb_release -a`

> No LSB modules are available.
>   Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
>   Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
>   Release:  16.04
>   Codename: xenial

`nmcli dev show | grep DNS` partial results:

> IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1

Which is the router address.

`
more /etc/resolve results:

```
 # Generated by OpenVPN Client UP Script  

 nameserver 10.8.0.1
```

`ls -1 /etc/resolv.conf` results:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 172 Feb 23 22:34 /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's my understanding that /etc/resolv.conf is for public nameservers only. It appears that yours has been modified to use a private nameserver ostensibly over a VPN. **If** you wish your Ubuntu box to obtain Domain Name Service normally to allow internet access, I suggest that you revert back to the default /etc/resolv.conf file which contains:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

You can revert back to the default `/etc/resolv.conf` file by either restoring the original from a recent backup from before it was modified, or opening the file the link points to with the command `sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf` and pasting the code from the default file above into it *overwriting it's current content*. You may want to save a copy of the current content beforehand as a backup somewhere you will be able to locate it if you find you need it.

NOTE: `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symbolic link to the file `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` so file based operations such as editing on /etc/resolv.conf will actually be carried out on `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`

To confirm that the link hasn't been erroneously modified run the command `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` which should result in the output below.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Feb 25 2016 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

the arrow indicates it's a symlink.

For more information on resolvconf which modifies this file see [the man page.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/resolvconf.8.html)

Comment: When I try to create the symbolic link using `ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`, I get: `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/resolv.conf': File exists`

Comment: OK, you've lost me now. Can you give me more detail on what I should be doing? `You'll have to remove the file you created after deleting the link to recreate it` makes no sense to me.

Comment: I didn't delete /etc/resolv.conf. I edited it as per your directions.

Comment: Well, something modified it inappropriately. See my updated answer.

Comment: Got it. Done & fixed.

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad we got it sorted! :-)

Comment: This answer fixed my issue too. In my case the **/etc/resolv.conf** does not have **nameserver 127.0.1.1**.

Answer (score 2):

**If you have an unmodifed /etc/resolv.conf file** (and you should) you should change <kbd>System Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Network</kbd> -> <kbd>Options</kbd> to be set as shown below so that your router will provide DNS services to your Ubuntu box as it does to your other systems.

[image: DHCP]

An alternative is to use [Google public DNS service](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) and add  8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as your DNS servers.

Comment: Switched over to settings as shown above. No change. Still can't get internet access.

Comment: Please [edit] the output of `more /etc/resolv.conf` into your post Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and my resolv.conf file was as shown in Elder Geek's post . I did : 
1. Changed System -> Network -> Options to Automatic(DHCP)
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get upgrade
4. Repeat Setp 2 and 3 multiple times.

I know this is not a very technical way of answering as it doesn't answer the root cause (or talk about it). But it worked for me. Let's see if it works for you.