# Ubuntu 16.04. Internet keep disconnecting. Local network is fine

Tags: 16.04, networking, internet, dns, disconnect

I have the same exact problem as this guy [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886252/ubuntu-16-04-lts-internet-connection-doesnt-work-but-network-still-can-access). My network connection is fine. I can ping to my router, connect to my local ftp server, login to antoher machine through ssh. The only problem is the internet connection. It keeps disconnecting aftere a few seconds every time I connect to the network. It happens with both wired and wireless connection. The weird thing is, ping to Google's IP address directly is fine. But not with domain address.

The guy who post the question I linked above seems to be able to solve his problem. But I can't understand how he did that since the answers to his question isn't clear enough for me. And I have no way to reach to him or to the person who answered his question. I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956288/no-internet-dns-problem-ubuntu-16-04-03), but no luck.

I hope I can find a solution here.

Here is the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search lan
```

Comment: Well the solution was adding the correct DNS nameserver. Please copy and paste the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` to your question (and format it as code)

Comment: Done. Although I find it strange, cause I didn't do any change to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because your DNS servers are not properly configured to avoid future problems you can change the following line in `/etc/network/interfaces` right at the end so that it looks like this:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

This will allow you to use Google's Public DNS. You can change the DNS servers to the ones provided by your ISP. 
When you are done save the file and run the command

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Or simply restart your computer

Comment: This fixed my problem. You're a saviour. Thanks a lot. 
Seriously though, this is clearly a defect on 16.04. Every distro I ever used never had this problem. Even the latest Debian Stable.

Comment: didn't help with ubuntu v 22.04